# How to loop through JSON list with nested dicts matchbook data?

Tags: python, json

Below is portion of data that I get from a json request. e.g one match of many matches schedules.

```
tennis_event_json = '''
    [
        {
            "TIMESTAMP": "2018-09-17 00:09:21.499540",
            "id": 910569150160041,
            "name": "A Rus vs V Flink",
            "sport-id": 9,
            "start": "2018-09-17T02:00:00.000Z",
            "in-running-flag": false,
            "allow-live-betting": true,
            "category-id": [
                9,
                410468520880009,
                456968853470009,
                476301248050010,
                595375589900009,
                899462538790042
            ],
            "status": "open",
            "volume": 1014.36488,
            "event-participants": [
                {
                    "id": 910569150220041,
                    "event-id": 910569150160041,
                    "participant-name": "V Flink",
                    "number": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 910569150230042,
                    "event-id": 910569150160041,
                    "participant-name": "A Rus",
                    "number": 1
                }
            ],
            "markets": [
                {
                    "live": false,
                    "event-id": 910569150160041,
                    "id": 910569150980042,
                    "name": "Moneyline",
                    "runners": [
                        {
                            "withdrawn": false,
                            "prices": [],
                            "event-id": 910569150160041,
                            "id": 910569151040041,
                            "market-id": 910569150980042,
                            "name": "A Rus",
                            "status": "open",
                            "volume": 733.19472,
                            "event-participant-id": 910569150230042
                        },
                        {
                            "withdrawn": false,
                            "prices": [],
                            "event-id": 910569150160041,
                            "id": 910569151040042,
                            "market-id": 910569150980042,
                            "name": "V Flink",
                            "status": "open",
                            "volume": 281.17016,
                            "event-participant-id": 910569150220041
                        }
                    ],
                    "start": "2018-09-17T02:00:00.000Z",
                    "status": "open",
                    "market-type": "money_line",
                    "type": "binary",
                    "in-running-flag": false,
                    "allow-live-betting": true,
                    "volume": 1014.36488,
                    "back-overround": 141.27861,
                    "lay-overround": 58.72139,
                    "number-of-winners": 1
                }
            ],
            "meta-tags": [
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "name": "Tennis",
                    "type": "SPORT",
                    "url-name": "tennis"
                },
                {
                    "id": 410468520880009,
                    "name": "Live Betting",
                    "type": "OTHER",
                    "url-name": "live-betting"
                },
                {
                    "id": 456968853470009,
                    "name": "Qualifiers",
                    "type": "OTHER",
                    "url-name": "qualifiers"
                },
                {
                    "id": 476301248050010,
                    "name": "Korea Rep",
                    "type": "COUNTRY",
                    "url-name": "korea-rep"
                },
                {
                    "id": 595375589900009,
                    "name": "WTA Seoul",
                    "type": "COMPETITION",
                    "url-name": "wta-seoul"
                },
                {
                    "id": 899462538790042,
                    "name": "September 16th 2018",
                    "type": "DATE",
                    "url-name": "september-16th-2018"
                }
            ],
            "Latency": 0.927759
        },
        {
            "TIMESTAMP": "2018-09-17 00:09:21.499540",
            "id": 910652994550042,
            "name": "C Liu vs D Khazaniuk",
            "sport-id": 9,
            "start": "2018-09-17T02:00:00.000Z",
            "in-running-flag": false,
            "allow-live-betting": true,
            "category-id": [
                9,
                410468520880009,
                423407498380010,
                456968853470009,
                595371288900009,
                899462538790042
            ],
            "status": "open",
            "volume": 328.95039,
            "event-participants": [
                {
                    "id": 910652994610041,
                    "event-id": 910652994550042,
                    "participant-name": "C Liu",
                    "number": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 910652994610042,
                    "event-id": 910652994550042,
                    "participant-name": "D Khazaniuk",
                    "number": 2
                }
            ],
            "markets": [
                {
                    "live": false,
                    "event-id": 910652994550042,
                    "id": 910652994860042,
                    "name": "Moneyline",
                    "runners": [
                        {
                            "withdrawn": false,
                            "prices": [
                                {
                                    "available-amount": 274.14118,
                                    "currency": "EUR",
                                    "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                                    "odds": 1.26315,
                                    "decimal-odds": 1.26315,
                                    "side": "back",
                                    "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                                },
                                {
                                    "available-amount": 364.54806,
                                    "currency": "EUR",
                                    "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                                    "odds": 1.23255,
                                    "decimal-odds": 1.23255,
                                    "side": "back",
                                    "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                                },
                                {
                                    "available-amount": 289.15565,
                                    "currency": "EUR",
                                    "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                                    "odds": 1.22727,
                                    "decimal-odds": 1.22727,
                                    "side": "back",
                                    "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                                },
                                {
                                    "available-amount": 112.42242,
                                    "currency": "EUR",
                                    "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                                    "odds": 1.35715,
                                    "decimal-odds": 1.35715,
                                    "side": "lay",
                                    "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                                },
                                {
                                    "available-amount": 277.83577,
                                    "currency": "EUR",
                                    "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                                    "odds": 1.36765,
                                    "decimal-odds": 1.36765,
                                    "side": "lay",
                                    "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                                },
                                {
                                    "available-amount": 150.76246,
                                    "currency": "EUR",
                                    "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                                    "odds": 1.40651,
                                    "decimal-odds": 1.40651,
                                    "side": "lay",
                                    "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                                }
                            ],
                            "event-id": 910652994550042,
                            "id": 910652994910041,
                            "market-id": 910652994860042,
                            "name": "C Liu",
                            "status": "open",
                            "volume": 253.72811,
                            "event-participant-id": 910652994610041
                        },
                        {
                            "withdrawn": false,
                            "prices": [
                                {
                                    "available-amount": 40.15086,
                                    "currency": "EUR",
                                    "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                                    "odds": 3.8,
                                    "decimal-odds": 3.8,
                                    "side": "back",
                                    "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                                },
                                {
                                    "available-amount": 102.14551,
                                    "currency": "EUR",
                                    "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                                    "odds": 3.72,
                                    "decimal-odds": 3.72,
                                    "side": "back",
                                    "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                                },
                                {
                                    "available-amount": 61.28556,
                                    "currency": "EUR",
                                    "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                                    "odds": 3.46,
                                    "decimal-odds": 3.46,
                                    "side": "back",
                                    "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                                },
                                {
                                    "available-amount": 72.14242,
                                    "currency": "EUR",
                                    "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                                    "odds": 4.8,
                                    "decimal-odds": 4.8,
                                    "side": "lay",
                                    "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                                },
                                {
                                    "available-amount": 84.77862,
                                    "currency": "EUR",
                                    "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                                    "odds": 5.3,
                                    "decimal-odds": 5.3,
                                    "side": "lay",
                                    "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                                },
                                {
                                    "available-amount": 65.71719,
                                    "currency": "EUR",
                                    "odds-type": "DECIMAL",
                                    "odds": 5.4,
                                    "decimal-odds": 5.4,
                                    "side": "lay",
                                    "exchange-type": "back-lay"
                                }
                            ],
                            "event-id": 910652994550042,
                            "id": 910652994920042,
                            "market-id": 910652994860042,
                            "name": "D Khazaniuk",
                            "status": "open",
                            "volume": 75.22228,
                            "event-participant-id": 910652994610042
                        }
                    ],
                    "start": "2018-09-17T02:00:00.000Z",
                    "status": "open",
                    "market-type": "money_line",
                    "type": "binary",
                    "in-running-flag": false,
                    "allow-live-betting": true,
                    "volume": 328.95039,
                    "back-overround": 104.43889,
                    "lay-overround": 95.56111,
                    "number-of-winners": 1
                }
            ],
            "meta-tags": [
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "name": "Tennis",
                    "type": "SPORT",
                    "url-name": "tennis"
                },
                {
                    "id": 410468520880009,
                    "name": "Live Betting",
                    "type": "OTHER",
                    "url-name": "live-betting"
                },
                {
                    "id": 423407498380010,
                    "name": "China",
                    "type": "COUNTRY",
                    "url-name": "china"
                },
                {
                    "id": 456968853470009,
                    "name": "Qualifiers",
                    "type": "OTHER",
                    "url-name": "qualifiers"
                },
                {
                    "id": 595371288900009,
                    "name": "WTA Guangzhou",
                    "type": "COMPETITION",
                    "url-name": "wta-guangzhou"
                },
                {
                    "id": 899462538790042,
                    "name": "September 16th 2018",
                    "type": "DATE",
                    "url-name": "september-16th-2018"
                }
            ],
            "Latency": 0.933854
        }
    ]
'''
```

Which can be loaded into Python for testing purposes via a:

```
tennis_event = json.loads(tennis_event_json)
```

I would like to get event-participant name and store them as

```
runner_1 = event-participant[0]
runner_2 = event-participant[1]
```

as there is two dicts in the lists event-participants
I would like to do the same for prices so I can have

```
runner_price_1 = odds[0]
runner_price_2 = odds[1]
```

Here's my code:

```
for data in tennis_event:
    id = data['id']
    event_name = data['name']
    sport_id = data['sport-id']
    stat_time = data['start']
    is_ip = data['in-running-flag']

    for mar in data['event-participants']:
        runner_1 = mar['participant-name'][0]
        runner_2 = mar['participant-name'][1]
        for pr in data['prices']:
          runner_pr_1 = pr['odds'][0]
          runner_pr_2 = pr['odds'][1]
          print(runner_1, runner_2, runner_pr_1, runner_pr_2)
```

When I try my code I only get the first letter for `runner_pr_1`.
What I want to do is get the each participant name and for the first `dict` in the event participant `list` name it as `runner_pr_1` I would like to do the same for the first `'odds'` too.

How do I do that?

Comment: Your formatting is incorrect for the third `for` loop. Make sure to indent the block that you want in the loop. Also, the reason you're only getting the first letter is because `mar['participant-name']` is the name, and `mar['participant-name'][0]` is the first letter of the name.

Comment: The formatting of the JSON data you have in your question is invalid and unparsable which makes it difficult for others to test their potential fixes to your code.

Comment: @martineau if you copy and paste that data into http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/
you will see its valid JSON. I have been able to parse some of the data already

Comment: It's wrong as posted in your question because it has many double-quoted strings that have been broken-up so they span across multiple lines. This make it invalid as far as Python's `json` module's `load()` and `loads()` functions are concerned.

Comment: @martineau can you point to a line that shows the double quoted strings? I can't see the  problem you mentioned yet

Comment: In the very first object in the `tennis_event` list there's the line `"participant-name": "S\n` that has the remainder of the quoted string continued onto the next line as `Soler - Espinosa ", "\n`. This raises a `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` in the Python 3.7 interpreter — so I misspoke about `json.load()` or `loads()` having a problem with it (but not about there being something wrong with its format).

Comment: To verify the problem wasn't introduced by edits others (including myself) made to your question, I just tried it again using what you had initially in it  before any changes were made. Although in that case it is _slightly_ different, it's still basically the same issue. The line is `910569160130041, "event-id": 910569159990041, "participant-name": "S \n` followed by the line `Soler-Espinosa", "number": 2}, {"id": 910569160130042, "event-id": \n` — which raises exactly the same `SyntaxError` exception. How did you obtain (or what's the source of) what's in your question?

Comment: @martineau Here is a gist of the full json response I'm working with I created yesterday. https://gist.github.com/Hey-tom/5dd6d61c7cfb28700405e6efd1ea5e7b
The solution below by pkpnd raises a key error.
I will also share the library I'm using to obtain the data and the code I'm running to get it.

This is the wrapper api i'm using. https://github.com/rozzac90/matchbook
Below is the code I'm using, You might need log in credentials to use matchbook api. all you need to do is create an account. the api use is free
https://gist.github.com/Hey-tom/e51894e7b3bbb365473b6eefcd231f76

Comment: tomoc4: Whoa dude, that's way more work than I'm willing to do to make your question answerable (much less answer it). However as a gesture of good-will, I've edited your question again and inserted a valid snippet of the JSON data which should help folks help you find a solution.

Comment: @martineau thanks so much for your help. I'm halfway there trying to solve this problem now. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this.
However, note that you might have to match player IDs because it's not guaranteed that the data in 'runners' is in the same order as participants.

```
for data in tennis_event:
    id = data['id']
    event_name = data['name']
    sport_id = data['sport-id']
    stat_time = data['start']
    is_ip = data['in-running-flag']

    mar = data['event-participants']
    runner_1 = mar[0]['participant-name']
    runner_2 = mar[1]['participant-name']
    runner_pr_1 = data['markets'][0]['runners'][0]['prices'][0]['odds']
    runner_pr_2 = data['markets'][0]['runners'][1]['prices'][0]['odds']
    print(runner_1, runner_2, runner_pr_1, runner_pr_2)
```

Comment: I'm getting a key error when I try your solution on my data. When I  try   runner_1 = mar['participant-name'] on it's own I get all runners. but I can't get the first occurrence. This is the full gist as the question data was only a portion. I don't think it will have an effect as it's the same style but with more events https://gist.github.com/Hey-tom/5dd6d61c7cfb28700405e6efd1ea5e7b

Comment: I tried your solution again and it works for getting the correct runners. When I try to get the prices I get list index out of range. could that be due to empty values ?

Comment: Yeah, if the prices list is empty, then accessing element 0 would get index out of range. Test the length of the list first: `if len(prices_list) > 0`